# Gitlab: How to approve merge request from myself

Tags: gitlab

The gitlab project is hosted at my company and created from some common template. I am the maintainer of the project.

I made code change, committed the branch and, at gitlab page, I created the merge request. The problem is, the "Merge" button is greyed out and I do not receive approval request email, so I am stuck here and have to wait for my colleague to approve it before I can merge. Is there a way I can make the merge before that?

I already tried the following at the project setting.

1. At "Merge request approvals", there is a rule mandates the minimum number of approvals. I deleted my colleagues from approvers list, just left myself; I also changed the minimum number to 0.
2. "Prevent approval of merge requests by merge request author" is unchecked
3. "Prevent approval of merge requests by merge request committers" is unchecked
4. In "repository" --> "Protected branch", I added 2 rules, one for the default branch of the project and one for the branch I just committed. The content of both rules are same, "allowed to merge" and "allowed to push" are "Maintainer + developer" and, the key is, "code  owner approval" is slide off.

But after all these, that "Merge" button at my merge request page is still disabled; the strange thing is, just above that button, I can see "Requires approval from Owners" is check marked.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Could you not close merge request and restart? Just so that you can be sure you did not do anything wrong during process. This is usually what I do when dealing with merge requests.

Comment: What do you mean "restart"?